# How Disabled Feature Policy in iframe?

Tags: javascript

I have a listener on the page that copies the text.

```
obj['this'].shadowRoot.querySelector(`div.${item}`).addEventListener('click',async (event)=>{
 event.currentTarget.style.background = '#faf671'
 let object = event.currentTarget
 let value = object.querySelector('p.value').innerHTML
 await navigator.clipboard.writeText(value)
 let timer = setTimeout((event)=>{
     object.style.background = '#4c6499de'
     clearTimeout(timer);
   }, 250);
})
```

Then I open the page in iframe and got this error:

```
waves-provider.mjs:831 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Disabled in this document by Feature Policy.
```

I added allow

But in internet i see example

```
allow="document-write https://www.google.com"
allow="fullscreen 'none'; geolocation 'none'"
```

but it's not work.

Comment: The iframe cannot have two `allow=""` attributes. If two are set, then one will be ignored.

Comment: It looks like the clipboard API permissions are not implemented in the Feature Policy yet: https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-feature-policy/issues/322

Comment: it is clipboard. But if i set   allow:"clipboard" is' not working

Comment: That should work in a near future. In the meantime, you will have to modify the `Feature-Policy` header from your server side.